# Why Cordova with webintent plugin is not work for me?

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, webintents

#### Result

- It's always stop at "APACHE CORDOVA connecting to device"
- I don't know why...

#### My Step

- 1.npm install -gd cordova
- 2.cordova create myapp
- 3.cd myapp
- 4.cordova platform add android
- 5.cordova plugin add https://github.com/InQBarna/WebIntent.git
- 6.cordova run android

#### Here is a part of my index.js:

```
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    document.onclick = function() {
        CDV.WEBINTENT.startActivity({
            action: CDV.WEBINTENT.ACTION_VIEW,
            url: 'geo:0,0?q=' + 'new york'
        },
        function() {}, function() {
            alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent')
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: You say you have a message box displaying the message instead of seeing your app start? If yes, it usually happens when you reach a timeout at app initialisation. It may be because you include files from the network in your html and it takes too long, or you run too slow code at app init or things like that.

Comment: I just want to launch another app from my app, like launch a google map, or others I created.

Comment: I was asking about the problem you encounter.

Comment: At first, I need to launch another App in my own app. so I searched and found the webintent plugin. I install it, but when I try to invoke it such as google map, It's not work for me, there are no google map app to be launched.

Answer (score 0):

you had multiple `},` and `;` inside your code.

```
receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    //I just try to launch a map view app.
    document.onclick = function() {
        alert(new Date);
        CDV.WEBINTENT.startActivity({
            action: CDV.WEBINTENT.ACTION_VIEW,
            url: 'geo:0,0?q=' + 'new york'
        }, function() {}, function() {
            alert('Failed to open URL via Android Intent')
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, That's my mistake in the sample code. I have update it.